# How can I match the ID between two json in a react app?

Tags: reactjs, json, loops

I have two json inside a react app and I want to filter the ids.

```
 {data.investments.map((item) => (
    <div className="tipo">
      <h1 key={item.id}>{item.description}</h1>
      <h2>
        Rendimento total: <span>valor</span>
      </h2>

      {/* SECOND LOOP  */}

      {data.reports.map((rep) => (
        <div>
          <Tabela reports={data.reports} tipoInvestimento={item.id} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  ))}
```

On the element inside the second loop, I need to show only the elements that match the Id with the first loop

```
    import React from "react";

export const Tabela = ({ reports }, { tipoInvestimento }) => {
  return (
    <table>
      {reports.map((r) => {
        if (r.id === tipoInvestimento) 
          return (
        <tr key={r.id}>
          <div>
            <td>
              {r.month}/{r.year}
            </td>
            <td>R$ {r.value.toFixed(2)}</td>
          </div>
          <td>{tipoInvestimento}</td>
        </tr>
      )}}
    </table>
  );
};
```

but nothing shows. Is there any other form to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to only iterate over some of the items based on a condition:

```
 {data.investments.map((item) => (
    <div className="tipo">
      <h1 key={item.id}>{item.description}</h1>
      <h2>
        Rendimento total: <span>valor</span>
      </h2>

      {/* SECOND LOOP  */}

      {data.reports.filter(r => r.id === item.id).map((rep) => (
        <div>
          <Tabela reports={data.reports} tipoInvestimento={item.id} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  ))}
```